# angular 1 $scope and Controller as, when $scope died?

Tags: angularjs

Since when exist "Controller as", it's does not exist since angular 1.2 ? released end of 2013 ? why people , books , blogs and tutorials has written  code with $scope , still in 2015,2014 ?

I've seen people with 1 or 2 years experience using angular 1.1 or angular 1.2 programming style in 2015 and 2016 , they were lost with angular 1.5, for example not using components.

Jobs ask for angular just ask for 'angular programmer' , they know there are big differences people that use every one angular in a different way, by example using $scope, or just directives and  not components, or they dont use ES2015 with babel?

I've never understood that. When really $scope died? 
If this question is not for stackoverflow, where i can post it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scope hasn't died, and probably will never do so. It's common to think that the `controllerAs` feature's came to replace `scope` but it doesn't. Actually, `controllerAs` comes to deprecate the viewmodel responsibility of `scope`, when before that, all the viewmodel's members of each template was declared on the component scope, now it's declared on the component's class `this`, and in the end, it become a member of scope isolating all features of your viewmodel in a single scope member internally.

Using `controllerAs` to handle your viewmodel is an excelent practice but, you still need `scope` to do, say, `scope` things. For example, emit and listen to events, handle disgestion cycle, etc. Therefore, `controllerAs` comes to separate viewmodel from real `scope` responsibilities. So, scope never really died at all, just changed how to use it a bit with an optimized feature.

Anyways, it doesn't mean that using old scope way is bad or either using controllers instead of components. Is highly recomended to adopt such practices, in large projects, it makes a lot of more sense than in small ones. Also, old project were built using old angularjs features so, an abrupt change like moving the entire project to the new way as `controllerAs` and `components` is not something <s>cheap</s> easy to do, especialy on large projects.

Comment: With a little bit of work, you can completely eliminate the need to litter your code with $scope. look at:  http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/21/five-guidelines-for-avoiding-scope-soup-in-angular.html    , so i think some  projects  can be written without scope

Comment: @stackdave if you have the opportunity of writing the project from scratch you may consider to use the style guide proposed by John Papahttps://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md